# d3.js 4.2 first element in selection not binding

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Simple question for someone checking out d3 4: 
https://jsfiddle.net/dwrzso58/

```
d3.select("body")
    .data([1,2,3])
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .text((d,i)=>d)
```

when this code runs only 2 and 3 show up in the DOM.  What gives with the first element in the array being lost?

Comment: Tormi's answer explained it: if you want your "enter" selection to have all your data, select something that doesn't exist. Have a look at this documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/2135/selections/16948/the-role-of-placeholders-in-enter-selections#t=201608142333397609478

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`d3.select("body")` selection contains one element so the `.data()` adds 1 to the selected body element and 2, 3 are left over and included into the `.enter()` pipeline. If you want to enter all three elements you have to call `.data()` on an empty selection like this:

```
d3.select("body").select("div")
.data([1,2,3])
.enter()
.append("div")
.text((d,i)=>d)
```